# Create two Automapper maps between the same two object types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, automapper

I am using AutoMapper in a WCF service to return `User` objects.  `User` has properties such as `AccountTeams` which itself has child objects.  All of the classes have AutoMapper maps.

Depending on the WCF `OperationContract` that is called, I want to return different amounts of data.  I want one `OperationContract` to return the `User` object without its `AccountTeams` property (and their children) populated and another `OperationContract` to return the `User` with the whole chain of properties filled out.

Is there a way to have two different maps between the same two objects or do I need to perform the full mapping and `null` out the properties I don't want to return from the service?

Comment: Have you considered the option of having two different `UserDTO` objects that are returned?

Comment: just for clarity, you are mapping from `User` to ??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kevin Kalitowski raised a good point about wal's answer: If we need two configurations to deal with a mapping that needs to be different, then don't we have to duplicate all the other mappings that are common?

I think I've found a way around this using profiles: Have one profile for each of the unique mappings, and a third profile for the common mappings.  Then create two configurations, one for each unique profile but also add the common profile to each configuration as well.

Example, in AutoMapper 4.2:

The classes to be mapped: User and Vehicle:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int FleetNumber { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
}
```

The profiles:

```
public class Profile1 : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<User, User>();
    }
}

public class Profile2 : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<User, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}

public class CommonProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<Vehicle, Vehicle>();
    }
}
```

Then create the configurations and map the objects:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var user = new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 };
    var vehicle = new Vehicle {FleetNumber = 36, Registration = "XYZ123"};

    var configuration1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<CommonProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<Profile1>();
    });

    var mapper1 = configuration1.CreateMapper();
    var mappedUser1 = mapper1.Map<User, User>(user);//maps both Name and Age
    var mappedVehicle1 = mapper1.Map<Vehicle, Vehicle>(vehicle);//Maps both FleetNumber 
                                                                //and Registration.

    var configuration2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<CommonProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<Profile2>();
    });

    var mapper2 = configuration2.CreateMapper();
    var mappedUser2 = mapper2.Map<User, User>(user);//maps only Name
    var mappedVehicle2 = mapper2.Map<Vehicle, Vehicle>(vehicle);//Same as mappedVehicle1.
}
```

I tried this out and it works.

Comment: That's such a simple answer I'm upset I didn't think of it. I'm changing the accepted answer to this one as it is a better fit for the question.

Comment: What about when using dependency injection. Is there a way to choose there?

Comment: @BradenBrown: Off the top of my head I can think of three possibilities: (1) You could inject two profiles - the common one and a unique one.  Inside your class you could then create your configuration from the profiles passed in.  And then create the mapper from the configuration;  (2) Alternately you could inject the configuration and create the mapper from it;  (3) A third alternative would be to inject the mapper.

Answer (score 15):

I am assuming you are mapping from `User` to `User` (if not then just change the destination type)

Assume this class for the following example:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use separate `AutoMapper.Configuration` to define 2 maps:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var configuration1 = new Configuration(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
    var mapper1 = new MappingEngine(configuration1);
    configuration1.CreateMap<User, User>();

    var user = new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 };
    var mappedUser1 = mapper1.Map<User, User>(user);//maps both Name and Age

    var configuration2 = new Configuration(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
    configuration2.CreateMap<User, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.Ignore());
    var mapper2 = new MappingEngine(configuration2);

    var mappedUser2 = mapper2.Map<User, User>(user);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, mappedUser2.Age);//maps only Name
}
```

To avoid mapping every other Type twice you could add a common method that takes a `Configuration` which maps everything that can be reached from `User` and call this on both `configuration1` and `configuration2` after the calls to `CreateMap`.

### Update

For Automapper 4.x use the following:

```
var configuration1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, User>();
});

var mapper1 = configuration1.CreateMapper();
var user = new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 };
var mappedUser1 = mapper1.Map<User, User>(user);//maps both Name and Age

var configuration2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.Ignore());
});

var mapper2 = configuration2.CreateMapper();
var mappedUser2 = mapper2.Map<User, User>(user);   //maps only Name
```

Comment: I assume this means I would have to map every other Type twice if it can be reached from User.  I was hoping for a way to override the map for just one object (User).  It sounds like that isn't possible.

Comment: i'm not sure if you can do that *however* you could add a common method that takes a `Configuration` which maps everything that can be reached from `User` and call this on both `configuration1` and `configuration2` after the calls to `CreateMap`

Comment: How should this be implemented with Automapper 4.x?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this problem with different Configuration objects as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic/2196854#2196854), you can find an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668962/automapper-c-using-the-instance-version-of-createmap-and-map-with-a-wcf-ser/7380377#7380377)

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to resolve such a scenario using a "**named wrapper class**" or a "**type alias**".
Models:

```cs
// db model
public User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountTeam> AccountTeams { get; set; } 
}

// view model
public UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AccountTeam[] AccountTeams { get; set; } 
}
// type alias for UserDto
public UserTeamsDto : UserDto
{
}
```

Mappings:

```cs
public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    // register this in global mappings
    public UserProfile()
    {
        // ignore AccountTeams
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountTeams, opt => opt.Ignore());
        // include AccountTeams
        CreateMap<User, UserTeamsDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountTeams,  opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.AccountTeams));
        // TODO: add `AccountTeam` mapping as well
    }
}
```

And Usage:

```cs
var usersWithoutTeams = await _dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 1)
    .ProjectTo<UserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

var usersWithTeams = await _dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 1)
    .ProjectTo<UserTeamsDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

// you can also do this since parent class is `UserDto`
UserDto[] parentClassList = usersWithTeams;
```

Hope this helps! Thanks!