# Stop model reference looping using auto-mapper MaxDepth

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have two models:

```
public class LocationMasterModel()
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int OtherAddressId { get; set; }
    public OtherAddress OtherAddress { get; set; }
}

public class OtherAddress()
{
    public int OtherAddressId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public LocationMasterModel LocationMaster { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<LocationMasterModel, LocationMasterViewModel>();
```

`LocationMasterViewModel` is another class that is just used for viewing purposes.

So when I try to get the location from my repository and try to convert from `LocationMasterModel` to `LocationMasterViewModel`, I need to stop the reference looping after one level of the hierarchy.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question, but!
If you have set up your mappers in the config, just can just choose to not include the extra relations and then the mappers won't map them?

Comment: yes . but i required that relations and  just want to stop after one hierarchy once model bind .using automapper like here when  locationmaster  get at that time other address automatically come but inside otheraddress not required location once again   .

Comment: Aha, think I understand now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266108/create-two-automapper-maps-between-the-same-two-object-types

This one explains some of it. But basically, you should define in the mapper, what should be mapped and when something should ignore the mapping