# AutoMapper - how to ignore null fields on the source, while using AutoMapper.Map - sometimes

Tags: c#, automapper

So we have a situation, where we are mapping from let's say `ThingDto`:

```
public class ThingDto {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid? SomeNiceId { get; set; }
}
```

and of course - the destination station `Thing`:

```
public class Thing {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid? SomeNiceId { get; set; }
}
```

With that as our context, here is the situation I am trying to solve:
We have the DTO as part of a public "contract" library that any outside solution can use in order to send us data. In most cases, when we want to use `AutoMapper` to map from the `ThingDto` to the `Thing` object, everything is peachy. By default, the values that are `null` on the `ThingDto` will "null-out" anything that is not null on the `Thing` object.

However, we have a situation where we need the `null` values on the source member (the `ThingDto`) just not map to the destination `Thing` object. We can do that with a `Condition` in the setup, but the issue is that we want to only do that *sometimes*. Is there a run-time setting that we can put when we are calling `AutoMapper.Map<ThingDto, Thing>(thingDto, thing);`?

This seems like something that would have been an issue for others as well - but no matter what I do I cannot find anything on it. There should be some sort of way to tell `AutoMapper` on the fly that we don't want to map nulls, but I am coming up with nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CreateMap<ThingDto, Thing>().ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, comment above would make the condition valid every time instead of only sometimes as asker requested

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting up multiple AutoMapper profiles for the same types, one that contains the Condition, one that doesn't, and then instantiating the configuration valid at that moment?

See:
[Create two Automapper maps between the same two object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266108/create-two-automapper-maps-between-the-same-two-object-types)

It might take a wrapper class to make it more maintainable, but I'd suggest something like this:

```
public class NormalProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<ThingDto, Thing>();
    }
}

public class ProfileWithCondition : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.CreateMap<ThingDto, Thing>().ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
    }
}
```

And in usage:

```
// Some code where you want to include NULL mappings would call this
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<NormalProfile>);
config.CreateMapper.Map<ThingDto, Thing>(thing);

// Code where you don't, would do this
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<ProfileWithCondition>);
config.CreateMapper.Map<ThingDto, Thing>(thing);
```

Comment: I will test this and see if it does what we are needing it to do.