# Different mapping rules for same entity types in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have two entities: *Order & OrderDTO* And I'm using **AutoMapper** to map them together.

Based on **some conditions** I want these entities to be **mapped differently**.

In fact I want **two or more different mapping rules** (`CreateMap`) for these entities.

And When calling `Map` function I want to tell the engine **which mapping rule to use**.

Thanks to this question: [Using the instance version of CreateMap and Map with a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668962/automapper-c-using-the-instance-version-of-createmap-and-map-with-a-wcf-ser/7380377#7380377) one approach is using a different instance of mapper so each one can has it's own mapping rules:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
var mapper = new MappingEngine(configuration);
configuration.CreateMap<Dto.Ticket, Entities.Ticket>()
```

**Do you have any better solution?**

As mentioned by **Jimmy Bogard (Creator of AutoMapper)** here: [Using Profiles in Automapper to map the same types with different logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic) :

> You're better off creating separate Configuration objects, and
>   creating a separate MappingEngine for each. The Mapper class is merely
>   a static facade over each of those, with some lifecycle management.

**What lifecycle management is needed to be done?**

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same thing. I've seen that answer but I don't get the way it works. Hope someone could help. Cheers.

Comment: @LeftyX: checkout my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up creating a new instance of mapper and caching them in a shared(static) concurrent dictionary.

here s my code (vb.net):

mapper factory:

```
Public Function CreateMapper() As IMapper Implements IMapperFactory.CreateMapper
            Dim nestedConfig = New ConfigurationStore(New TypeMapFactory, MapperRegistry.Mappers)
            Dim nestedMapper = New MappingEngine(nestedConfig)
            Return New AutomapperMapper(nestedConfig, nestedMapper)
 End Function
```

different profiles for different scenarios:

```
Private Shared _mapperInstances As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, IMapper)

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Profile(profileName As String) As IMapper
            Get
                Return _mapperInstances.GetOrAdd(profileName, Function() _mapperFactory.CreateMapper)
            End Get
End Property
```

and the mapper class:

```
Friend Class AutomapperMapper
        Implements IMapper

        Private _configuration As ConfigurationStore
        Private _mapper As MappingEngine

        Public Sub New()
            _configuration = AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
            _mapper = AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(configuration As ConfigurationStore, mapper As MappingEngine)
            _configuration = configuration
            _mapper = mapper
        End Sub

        Public Sub CreateMap(Of TSource, TDestination)() Implements IMapper.CreateMap
            _configuration.CreateMap(Of TSource, TDestination)()
        End Sub

        Public Function Map(Of TSource, TDestination)(source As TSource, destination As TDestination) As TDestination Implements IMapper.Map
            Return _mapper.Map(Of TSource, TDestination)(source, destination)
        End Function

        Public Function Map(Of TSource, TDestination)(source As TSource) As TDestination Implements IMapper.Map
            Return _mapper.Map(Of TSource, TDestination)(source)
        End Function


    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and I found that [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is upgraded to 4.2.0 one month ago, which begins to [support instances mappers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1031) created by different configurations, and the static mapper functions are marked obsoleted. So we don't need to implement by ourselves from now on!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Cheers.